# Create CSV from DataTable Object

Tags: jquery, ruby, csv, datatable, export

I am currently trying to make a customized CSV from a data table with JQuery. I've created a custom export button:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.my_button
```

And I'm currently extending CSV and writing my logic in the customize method. The problem with this is it's resulting in a lot of code parsing through the CSV and it just seems harder than it should be for me to create the CSV I need. I'm trying to combine data cells, change the headers, etc.

It would be a lot easier if I could just read from the DataTable API object that gets passed to the customize method and build my own CSV from scratch from that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is actually very easy.. all you need to do is reset the csv to a blank string and then you can build it back up.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.custom_1= {
    className: 'buttons-alert',
    extend: 'csv',
    text: 'SalesForce',
    filename: 'salesforce_export',

    customize: function(csv, button, dataTable){
       csv = 'New Column,New Column 2'
       dataTable.rows().every(function (rowId, tableLoop, rowLoop){
           var row_data = this.data();
           var custom_column_1 = row_data.cell + '$';
           var custom_column_2 = row_data.cell2 + ', ' + row_data.cell3;
           var row = [custom_column_1,custom_column_2].join();
           row += '\n';
           csv += row; 
       });
       return csv;
    }
}
```